# Doubletap with Finger.js Array of divs Single Call Single Selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, tap

How would i assign the selector of these Divs individually to the Jquery call
(dont worry about the ondblclick event , thats for mouseclick)

il show you the code as it is pretty self explanatory.

```
<div id='infotextinner' class='infotextinner' >

<div id='infobutton1'  class='infobuttons' ondblclick="dblclicked(this);" >Home & Garden</div>

<div id='infobutton2'  class='infobuttons' ondblclick="dblclicked(this);"  >Sports</div>

<div id='infobutton3'  class='infobuttons' ondblclick="dblclicked(this);"  >Electronics</div>

<div id='infobutton4'  class='infobuttons' ondblclick="dblclicked(this);"  >Jewelry</div>

<div id='infobutton5'  class='infobuttons' ondblclick="dblclicked(this);"  >Cosmetics</div>

<div id='infobutton6'  class='infobuttons' ondblclick="dblclicked(this);"  >Fashion</div>

<div id='infobutton7'  class='infobuttons' ondblclick="dblclicked(this);"  >Collectables</div>  

<div id='infobutton8'  class='infobuttons' ondblclick="dblclicked(this);"  >Pets & Animals</div>

<div id='infobutton9'  class='infobuttons' ondblclick="dblclicked(this);"  >Vehicles</div>

<div id='infobutton10'  class='infobuttons' ondblclick="dblclicked(this);"  >Houses/Flats</div>

<div id='infobutton11'  class='infobuttons' ondblclick="dblclicked(this);"  >Jobs/work</div>

<div id='infobutton12'  class='infobuttons' ondblclick="dblclicked(this);"  >Fashion</div>

<div id='infobutton13'  class='infobuttons' ondblclick="dblclicked(this);"  >Collectables</div> 

<div id='infobutton14'  class='infobuttons' ondblclick="dblclicked(this);"  >Pets & Animals</div>

<div id='infobutton15'  class='infobuttons' ondblclick="dblclicked(this);"  >Vehicles</div>

<div id='infobutton16'  class='infobuttons' ondblclick="dblclicked(this);"  >Houses/Flats</div>

<div id='infobutton17'  class='infobuttons' ondblclick="dblclicked(this);"  >Jobs/work</div>

</div>




THE JQUERY CALL



<script>
// direct event
$('#infobutton1').on('doubletap', function() {alert('doubletapp 1') });

$('#infobutton2').on('doubletap', function() {alert('doubletapp 2') });

$('#infobutton3').on('doubletap', function() {alert('doubletapp 3') });

$('#infobutton4').on('doubletap', function() {alert('doubletapp 4') });

$('#infobutton5').on('doubletap', function() {alert('doubletapp 5') });

$('#infobutton6').on('doubletap', function() {alert('doubletapp 6') });

$('#infobutton7').on('doubletap', function() {alert('doubletapp 7') });

$('#infobutton8').on('doubletap', function() {alert('doubletapp 8') });

$('#infobutton9').on('doubletap', function() {alert('doubletapp 9') });

$('#infobutton10').on('doubletap', function() {alert('doubletapp 10') });

$('#infobutton11').on('doubletap', function() {alert('doubletapp 11') });

$('#infobutton12').on('doubletap', function() {alert('doubletapp 12') });

$('#infobutton13').on('doubletap', function() {alert('doubletapp 13') });

$('#infobutton14').on('doubletap', function() {alert('doubletapp 14') });

$('#infobutton15').on('doubletap', function() {alert('doubletapp 15') });

$('#infobutton16').on('doubletap', function() {alert('doubletapp 16') });

$('#infobutton17').on('doubletap', function() {alert('doubletapp 17') });


</script>
```

I have a Jquery plugin capturing a doubletap event , but i have wet coded every selector with a separate call.

How would i do the same with a .this or any other method of selecting the divs individually so i donnot have to wet code them.

As in a simple 1 liner that captures the tap event of any of the divs individually and fires the jquery with the clicked selector..

If that makes any sense..

Recent Edit (sorry for messing anybody about, i should of done a little more research.

The Answer i found is as follows

```
<script>
    $("#infotextinner").children().each(function(index) {

    $(this).on('doubletap', function()  { var ClickId = $(this).attr('id'); alert(ClickId) })  });
<script>
```

many thanks.

Again i'l do my research Next Time, i promise..